# Japanese fonts not getting displayed properly when running on Unix box

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, unix, character-encoding

I have a Spring MVC based Java webapp. I have some data to be displayed in Japanese fonts. I did some online research and noticed that UTF-8 is the charset encoding I need. I added the below line into my app. All it does is adds charset encoding to response header.

```
 response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

When I test on Windows 7 Japanese fonts are showing up properly.

when I ran the same war file on a Unix box, I see only these characters: ��� and numbers if any . I checked the response header in Chrome Debugger and I still see UTF-8 encoding.

The only difference i see in header information is windows has server as Apache-Coyote/1.1 while the one on unix has apache.

Can some suggest what else I need to check?

Comment: Have you checked your Apache's `server.xml` to see whether the URIencoder is set to UTF8? if not add this line to connector tag :`    <Connector URIEncoding="utf-8" .... />` .

Comment: i added it. no change

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be how the string is created.  Is it read from a file?

If so, the file itself has an encoding and you are likely reading it in according to the default platform encoding.  If the file is in one encoding, but you read it in another, the text in your String will be incorrect to begin with.

A quick check using debugging/logging is the length of the String.  If it reports one length on Windows and another on Unix, then there is probably an encoding error while generating the string. An example is when a character in UTF-8 is interpreted as ISO-8859, and you see something like this: â€“

In this case, you would expect the String to have a length of 1, but it has a length of 3.  If that was embedded in some other text, you would see a difference of 2 in the lengths, even though the text should be the same.

Comment: i get from sql db. i am not reading from file. All i see are these characters ��� in unix.

Comment: Oh.  Then this answer is completely off base.  The "?" characters indicate that your font does not have the Japanese glyphs it is being asked to display.  Try a different font, particularly one you know to contain Japanese glyphs.

Comment: can you give me some more detail on how can i try different font. I have no idea

Comment: You need to find a font on your Unix system that contains the Japanese characters.  To try that font, use a CSS font specifier that will cause this font to be selected when it is available.  Unfortunately, if the font is not there, you will not get the Japanese glyphs to display.  It's not something you can control from the server.

Comment: I added that font. still no change.

Comment: I'm running out of clever suggestions.  Is your web page visible at a public URL?